# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header for axios post request to aws lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, axios, aws-api-gateway

I'm having trouble making a post request to a lambda function with axios in my web app.  I get back the error message "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'lambdalink' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Code for the axios request:

```
const config = {
      method: 'post',
      url: 'lambdalink',
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
      data: {
        info: JSON.stringify(data)
      }
    };

    Axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

When I make the request without the data param in the config the request goes through just fine, but once I add data to it I get that error.  My CORS configuration for the lambda function is as follows:

**Access-Control-Allow-Origin:**

"*", "http://localhost:4200/", "http://localhost:4200"

**Access-Control-Allow-Headers:**

"access-control-allow-origin"

**Access-Control-Allow-Methods:**

"POST"

I've tried different combinations of these settings, but no luck.  Am I missing something server side or am I just not handling CORS correctly in the browser?